# Covert Ionic Capacitor to base64String Camera.pickImages

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

```
    import { Camera, CameraResultType, CameraSource, GalleryPhoto } from '@capacitor/camera';
const images =  await Camera.pickImages({
      quality: 100,
      presentationStyle: 'fullscreen',
      limit: 5,
    });
```

How to convert images into base64String to upload to server?

Comment: First you gotta learn this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And then read the documentation: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/next/apis/camera#galleryphoto tells you to use the returned path with https://capacitorjs.com/docs/next/apis/filesystem plugin so you can read the path as a base64 string.